# TSQL Append rows to a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm declaring a `varchar` variable in T-SQL

```
declare @var varchar(max);
```

I have a select query which returns more than one value. Such as:

```
Select name from table where ...
```

I want to append each row to this variable. For example my query returns:

```
name
----------
 Joe
 Jack
 William
 Avarel
```

I want my `@var` to be this: `JoeJackWilliamAvarel`

How can I do it? I'm writing this query but it gives me error:

```
Set @var = (Select name from table where ...)
```

And the error is:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT
  @var = @var + name
FROM
  table
WHERE
  ...
ORDER BY
  ...
```

But make sure @var does *NOT* start as NULL.  `@set @var = ''`.

Comment: actually it was so simple, how couldn't i think about it, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @var = COALESCE(@var+ ' ', '') +  name
FROM  table
WHERE ....
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: I think ISNULL() is sufficient here.

Answer (score 2):

Following query may be used as Sub Query or use individually.

```
SET @var = (SELECT name + ' ' 
            FROM   mytable 
            Where ...
            FOR xml path (''))
```